# Cannot find X.509 certificate StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType 'FindBySubjectName', FindValue ''

Tags: iis, certificate, x509

I have added the certificate to Trusted root certification Authorities.
But still my code is giving this error when I start my REST service.

Error:

```
 Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType 'FindBySubjectName', FindValue '<certificate name>'.
```

In Web.config, I have added the below tag:

```
<serviceCertificate findValue="<certificate name>"
                    x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                    storeLocation="LocalMachine" />
</serviceCredentials>
```

Please let me know if I am doing it incorrectly?

Comment: Use x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" and specify thumbprint of the certificate from LocalMachine\My store that has also a private key.

Comment: I tried using thumbprint also. now it gives error as Invalid hexadecimal string format.

Comment: Open the certificate in mmc. Scroll down in details to thumbprint. Select thumbprint but beware of invisible char at the beginning. Better select from second char to the end and type first char manually.

Comment: I have done the same but still getting the same error.

Comment: @pepo Also, i have just added my certificate in mmc..are there any other additional steps to install it? I had 2 files one .crt and one .pfx.. I have just added the crt file.

Comment: pfx file contains certificate and corresponding private key. It can also contain certificate of CA. crl file contains only certificate. Import pfx file to LocalMachine\My store. If crt file contains certificate of CA that issued certificate in pfx file then import crt file in trusted root store.

Comment: by the way your XML node is closed two times...  with `<element/>` and with `</element>`.

Comment: @pepo 1) I have added pfx file as well.. can you please let me know what is "StoreName 'My'" and how can we change that..I am still getting the same error.2) If i have to find by thumbprint which one to take - the certificate or pfx thumbprint?

Comment: In MMC StoreName My represents Personal store. All certificates with private keys should be in this store. When you import pfx to LocalMachine\My store then use thumbprint of this certificate. It should be the thumbprint of certificate which has private key. It should not be thumbprint of CA. Also if you open details of this pfx certificate you should see whole certificate chain built. If certificate chain is not built correctly then it will not work.

Comment: thanks @pepo Certificate error has gone.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Manage computer certificates". Click that and you should get **"certlm"** window
Expand personal folder and then certificate folder and look for the certificate you have provided in your web.config. I think your certificate name is wrong and that is why you getting this error.

my web.config setting is

and in my **"certlm"** window i got my certificate with name of device.DEVELOPMENT. look at the following image for my certificate info[image]

Please mark it as answer if this solution helps you in solving ur problem